# Using C# for programming devices and machines

Tags: c#, .net, device

I recently found out about [AR.Drone](http://ardrone2.parrot-ardrone.cz/) and the fact that it can be programmed using C#. I already know about XBox and Kinect and I was wondering if there are any other devices, toys or machines that can be programmed with C#? I don't mind if 3rd-part libraries are required to do so.

I also know about .NET Gadgeteer, but I don't want to build a device my self.

Comment: Why down voting !? please leave a comment when you down vote!

Comment: Not downvoting, but: SO is for specific questions, that ideally have one definite answer. Open questions like "what language should I learn?", "what's the best tool to do X?" or almost any kind of question where possible answers are in list form are discouraged.

Comment: I still do not understand why this rule exists...

Comment: I know that this is not the idela question for SO, but for what forum website then? Where can I find many C# interested people with different kinds of experience? IS there a better place to ask such a question?

Comment: Xbox is programmable with C# because it (used to?) run a subset of .NET. There are not many other toys or devices that implement the CLR. However, almost any device that comes with an SDK has a .NET wrapper (and if not, you can write one). This differs in that your application doesn't _run_ on the device, but merely _sends commands_ to the device, for example over bluetooth or wifi. So almost _any_ such device can be programmed against using C#, even your coffee maker if it has a network connection. That's why this question is a bit broad. Narrow down and try programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah, thank you for your explanation. I was not aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lego Mindstorm EV3 is fun. Have a look at this post as to how to control it using C#/tcpIp

http://siouxnetontrack.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/connecting-the-pc-to-our-ev3/

Here is a library for using bluetooth.

http://ev3messenger.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

For a mindstorms library have a look at my library at www.monobrick.dk